# Does Google Play include all mipmap densities when downloading app?

Tags: android, google-play

I've tried searching around a bit, without any luck. I've developed some apps that uses a lots of images (Mostly 200*200 pixels in size). I'd like to support different screen sizes by adding different sizes of the images, but since that would increase the apk with many MegaBytes, I need to know if a device downloads all the mipmap-densities, or just the one meant for its own screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It contains all densities currently. Perhaps this will change in the future. You as a developer can split your apk into multiple apks for different densities and upload them as split-apk to google-play.

Comment: I've already done that for localized graphics, but didn't think about doing the same for different densities. I tried avoiding making to many akp's, though. But thanks for a good answer and suggestion!